# Get all customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

Can anyone help me to get all available customer groups?

I want to find customer group names and their ids.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code run it from your magento dir:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
foreach($customer as $type) {
    echo '<pre>Customer group id :'.$type->getCustomerGroupId().'<br>';
    echo '<pre>Customer group code :'.$type->getCustomerGroupCode().'<br>';

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following function

```
$groups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
foreach ($groups as $Group) {

  echo 'Customer GroupID = '.$Group->getCustomerGroupId().'<br>';
  echo 'Customer Group Name = '.$Group->getCustomerGroupCode().'<br>';

}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Yes I have tried that but I am not getting how to get all customer group names and ids from it?

Comment: Modified my answer check it